# Help understanding the hibernate behavior/error

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Product class which has a 1-to-many association to itself (composite pattern). Below are the pojo, hbm, test code and log/error respectively. Can someone explain what this error is about. Why am I getting this error when setting the parent's primary key?

**Product pojo**

```
public class Product
{
    private Long id;

    private Set<Product> children = Collections.emptySet();

    public void addChild(final Product child)
    {
        if (children.isEmpty())
        {
            children = Sets.newHashSet();
        }
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

**hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
        <set name="children" lazy="false" table="PRODUCT">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Product" />
        </set>
</class>
```

**Test**

```
public void save()
    {
        // Level 1 - mortgage LOB
        Product mortgage = new Product();
        mortgage.setCode("Mortgage");

        Product ml = new Product();
        ml.setCode("Mortgage Loan");

        Product me = new Product();
        me.setCode("Home Equity LOC");

        //Level 2
        mortgage.addChild(ml);
        mortgage.addChild(me);

        hibernateTemplate.save(mortgage);
    }
```

**log and error**

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] insert into PRODUCT (ID, CODE, NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ISDECISIONABLE, ISSELECTABLE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.StringType] binding 'Mortgage' to parameter: 1
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.StringType] binding null to parameter: 2
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.TimestampType] binding null to parameter: 3
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.TimestampType] binding null to parameter: 4
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.BooleanType] binding 'false' to parameter: 5
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.BooleanType] binding 'false' to parameter: 6
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] call identity()
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL] update PRODUCT set ID=? where ID=?
DEBUG [org.hibernate.type.LongType] binding '1' to parameter: 1
ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.Product
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:78)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transient object is one that has not been saved.  As mapped, your relationship does not use any 'transitive persistence', that is to say, you have not told hibernate that when you save the parent you want to save the children.  I guess the error is because you have instances of the children (doesn't matter that the children have the same class of the parent) on the parent (in the session), and hibernate is aware of that, but it doesn't know what to do with them.

You can either:

1) save the children before saving the parent
2) add the 'cascade' attribute to your mapping, something like cascade="save" or cascade="all"

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive

Comment: @hvgotcodes +1 but here it is only trying to save the parent product "mortgage". hibernate is not even trying to save the child objects yet. My understanding is that I should only get this error while hibernate tries to save the children...am i missing something?

Comment: @pangea, yes but your parent "Mortage" has a collection in it to other Products.  You have set a up a relationship from the Mortgage to whatever ml and me are, which are also children.  Because you put the children in the Parent's set, hibernate sees them on the session.  But it cant set up the relationship properly because they haven't been saved, and you haven't told hibernate to save them when you save the parent.

Comment: @hvgotcodes Also, the link also says "t does NOT usually make sense to enable cascade on a <many-to-one> or <many-to-many> association"

Comment: @hvgotcodes right I had many-to-one earlier and later changed it. I wish I could give more than 1 upvote for your 1st comment

Comment: @pangea, no worries.  If the answer helped you solve your issue and get better understanding of hibernate, I am happy.

Comment: @hvgotcodes after adding cascade="save-update" to the collection mapping I am getting the below error: ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] failed batch
ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)

Comment: @hvgotcodes log: insert into PRODUCT (ID, CODE, NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ISDECISIONABLE, ISSELECTABLE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding 'Mortgage' to parameter: 1
binding null to parameter: 2
binding null to parameter: 3
binding null to parameter: 4
binding 'false' to parameter: 5
binding 'false' to parameter: 6
Hibernate: call identity()
insert into PRODUCT (ID, CODE, NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ISDECISIONABLE, ISSELECTABLE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding 'Mortgage Loan' to parameter: 1

Comment: binding null to parameter: 2
binding null to parameter: 3
binding null to parameter: 4
binding 'false' to parameter: 5
binding 'false' to parameter: 6
Hibernate: call identity()
update PRODUCT set ID=? where ID=?
binding '1' to parameter: 1
binding '2' to parameter: 2
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

Comment: @pangea, i cant make sense of that...update your question or start a new one -- seems like you are having issues with the sql generated...you might want to post your full mapping and the dao method you are using to save

Comment: @hvgotcodes - tx posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100191/hibernate-exception-while-saving-with-cascade-save-update

Answer (score 0):

well I don't think that is all your code rigth? because in your pojo you need to have getters and setters for your Set. And try to saveyour Product this way:

```
Set children=new HashSet();
Product p=new Product(); 
Product p1=new Product(); 
Product p2=new Product();
children.add(p1);
children.add(p2);
p.setChildren(children);
hibernateTemplate.save(p);
```

But put cascade="all" or cascade="save-update" in your set mapping.

Comment: I have this code but removed for brevity. By adding cascade="all" I am getting another exception. posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100191/hibernate-exception-while-saving-with-cascade-save-update