# Hibernate exception while saving with cascade="save-update"

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is my hbm and test code respectively. I am using Spring's HibernateTemplate. I doesn't use DAO. Hibernate 2.2.5 with Spring 2.0.7

**hbm**

```
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_SN</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <set name="children" lazy="false" table="PRODUCT" cascade="save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Product" />
        </set>
        <property name="code" type="java.lang.String" column="CODE" not-null="true" />
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="NAME" />
        <property name="startDate" type="java.util.Date" column="STARTDATE" />
        <property name="endDate" type="java.util.Date" column="ENDDATE" />
        <property name="decisionable" type="boolean" column="ISDECISIONABLE" />
        <property name="selectable" type="boolean" column="ISSELECTABLE" />
    </class>
```

**Test**

```
public class ProductTest extends HibernateTestCase
{
    @Test
    public void save()
    {
        // Level 1 - mortgage LOB
        Product mortgage = new Product();
        mortgage.setCode("Mortgage");

        Product ml = new Product();
        ml.setCode("Mortgage Loan");

        Product me = new Product();
        me.setCode("Home Equity LOC");

        mortgage.addChild(ml);
        // mortgage.addChild(me);

        hibernateTemplate.save(mortgage);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getHbmResourceUnderTest()
    {
        return Lists.newArrayList("Product.hbm.xml");
    }
}
```

**Super test class**

```
public abstract class HibernateTestCase
{
    protected HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    protected TransactionTemplate transTemplate;

    public TransactionTemplate getTransTemplate()
    {
        return transTemplate;
    }

    protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.USER, "sa");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, HSQLDialect.class.getName());
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");
        configuration.setProperty(Environment.STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, "5");

        for (String resource : getHbmResourceUnderTest())
        {
            configuration.addResource(resource);
        }
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        transTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    }

    public abstract List<String> getHbmResourceUnderTest();
}
```

**Error**

```
insert into PRODUCT (ID, CODE, NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ISDECISIONABLE, ISSELECTABLE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding 'Mortgage' to parameter: 1
binding null to parameter: 2
binding null to parameter: 3
binding null to parameter: 4
binding 'false' to parameter: 5
binding 'false' to parameter: 6
Hibernate: call identity()
insert into PRODUCT (ID, CODE, NAME, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, ISDECISIONABLE, ISSELECTABLE) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
binding 'Mortgage Loan' to parameter: 1
binding null to parameter: 2
binding null to parameter: 3
binding null to parameter: 4
binding 'false' to parameter: 5
binding 'false' to parameter: 6
Hibernate: call identity()
update PRODUCT set ID=? where ID=?
binding '1' to parameter: 1
binding '2' to parameter: 2
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] failed batch
ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:390)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:632)
    at com.equifax.ic.platform.domain.product.ProductTest.save(ProductTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the root cause was the invalid mapping on my part for the collection. Thanks to this [article on composite mapping](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CompositePattern)

Wrong:

```
<key>
  <column name="ID" />
</key>
```

Correct

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="Product" lazy="false" column="PARENT" />

<set name="children" lazy="false" fetch="join" table="PRODUCT" cascade="all">
  <key>
    <column name="PARENT" />
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Product" />
</set>
```

Complete mapping

```
<class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="ID">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_SN</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="parent" class="Product" lazy="false" column="PARENT" />

        <set name="children" lazy="false" fetch="join" table="PRODUCT" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="PARENT" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Product" />
        </set>
        <property name="code" type="java.lang.String" column="CODE" not-null="true" />
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="NAME" />
        <property name="startDate" type="java.util.Date" column="STARTDATE" />
        <property name="endDate" type="java.util.Date" column="ENDDATE" />
        <property name="decisionable" type="boolean" column="ISDECISIONABLE" />
        <property name="selectable" type="boolean" column="ISSELECTABLE" />
    </class>
```

Answer (score 0):

since instances of the same class are both parents and children, you need an id, which you have, but you also need a parent-id type column in the db (and field on the class) so the children can have a reference to their parent.

See https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1004163

Comment: @hggotcodes this is working WITHOUT having the parent when I set inverse="true"...any idea why?

Comment: also adding this giving me the same error: <many-to-one name="parent" class="Product" lazy="false" column="PARENTID" />. only adding inverse="true" works ;-(

Answer (score 0):

When you made a bidirectional relationship you need to put inverse=true otherwise hibernate is going to try to do a double access and that is why you are getting a exception. Hibernate needs to know which side of the relationship is the one who has the control of saving and updating.